# FuncAnimation difficulty with markevery

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I would like to sequentially plot a series of x,y coordinates while marking specified coordinates distinctly. It seems that 'markevery' allows users to do this in matplotlib plots, however, when I provide this property in my animation, I receive the error 'ValueError: `markevery` is iterable but not a valid form of numpy fancy indexing'. Any thoughts?

My actual 'mark_on' array will be much longer, so I think that using a linecollection isn't reasonable here.

```
frames = 100
def update_pos(num,data,line):
    line.set_data(data[...,:num])
    return line, 

def traj_ani(data):
    fig_traj = plt.figure()    
    l,= plt.plot([],[],'b', markevery = mark_on, marker = '*')
    plt.xlim(-90,90)
    plt.ylim(-90,90)
    pos_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig_traj, update_pos, frames = np.shape(data)[1], fargs = (data,l),
                                  interval = 20, blit = True)
    pos_ani.save('AgentTrajectory.mp4')

data = pd.read_csv('xy_pos.csv', header = None, skiprows = [0])
data = np.asarray(data)
mark_on = [20, 50, 100, 300, 600]
traj_ani(data)
```

Thanks!

Here is a complete, mini example of an animation that works:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
import csv 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=2000, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

def update_pos(num,data,line):
    line.set_data(data[...,:num])
    return line, 

def traj_ani(data):
    fig_traj = plt.figure()    
    l,= plt.plot([],[],'b')
    plt.xlim(0,1)
    plt.ylim(0,1)
    pos_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig_traj, update_pos, frames = 25, fargs = (data,l),
                                  interval = 200, blit = True)
    pos_ani.save('AgentTrajectory.mp4')


data = np.random.rand(2,25)
traj_ani(data)
```

In my full code, I would like to specify certain frames whose x-y coordinate should be marked with either a special character or by a different color.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of the issue? Does is work without the animation? Does it work without markevery beeing set?

Comment: I've added a toy example of code that produces the type of animation that I want. When I add the markevery as in the first code, I receive the same ValueError. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems problematic to set a list of indizes to markevery, which contains indices not present in the ploted array. E.g. if the plotted array has 3 elements but the list set for markevery contains an index 5, a ValueError occurs.

The solution would need to be to set the markevery list in every iteration and make sure it only contains valid indizes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
import numpy as np 

mark_on = np.array([2,5,6,13,17,24])

def update_pos(num,data,line):
    line.set_data(data[...,:num])
    mark = mark_on[mark_on < num]
    line.set_markevery(list(mark))
    return line, 

def traj_ani(data):
    fig_traj = plt.figure()    
    l,= plt.plot([],[],'b', markevery = [], marker = '*', mfc="red", mec="red", ms=15)
    plt.xlim(0,1)
    plt.ylim(0,1)
    pos_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig_traj, update_pos, frames = 25, fargs = (data,l),
                                  interval = 200, blit = True)
    plt.show()

data = np.random.rand(2,25)
traj_ani(data)
```